# Extraction speed in Matrix package is very slow compared to regular matrix class

Tags: r, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix

This is an example of comparing row extraction from large matrices, sparse and dense, using the [Matrix package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) versus the regular `R` [base-matrix](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/base/html/matrix.html) class.

For dense matrices the speed is almost 395 times faster for the base class `matrix`:

```
library(Matrix)
library(microbenchmark)

## row extraction in dense matrices
D1<-matrix(rnorm(2000^2), 2000, 2000)
D2<-Matrix(D1)
> microbenchmark(D1[1,], D2[1,])
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
 D1[1, ]   14.437   15.9205   31.72903   31.4835   46.907   75.101   100
 D2[1, ] 5730.730 5744.0130 5905.11338 5777.3570 5851.083 7447.118   100
```

For sparse matrices it is almost 63 times in favor of `matrix` again.

```
## row extraction in sparse matrices
S1<-matrix(1*(runif(2000^2)<0.1), 2000, 2000)
S2<-Matrix(S1, sparse = TRUE)
microbenchmark(S1[1,], S2[1,])
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 S1[1, ]   15.225   16.417   28.15698   17.7655   42.9905   45.692   100
 S2[1, ] 1652.362 1670.507 1771.51695 1774.1180 1787.0410 5241.863   100
```

Why the speed discrepancy, and is there a way to speed up extraction in [Matrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) package?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what the trouble is, possibly S4 dispatch (which could potentially be a big piece of a small call like this). I was able to get performance equivalent to `matrix` (which has a pretty easy job, indexing + accessing a contiguous chunk of memory) by (1) switching to a row-major format and (2) writing my own special-purpose accessor function. I don't know exactly what you want to do or if it will be worth the trouble ...

Set up example:

```
set.seed(101)
S1 <- matrix(1*(runif(2000^2)<0.1), 2000, 2000)
```

Convert to column-major (`dgCMatrix`) and row-major (`dgRMatrix`) forms:

```
library(Matrix)
S2C <- Matrix(S1, sparse = TRUE)
S2R <- as(S1,"dgRMatrix")
```

Custom accessor:

```
my_row_extract <- function(m,i=1) {
    r <- numeric(ncol(m))   ## set up zero vector for results
    ## suggested by @OttToomet, handles empty rows
    inds <- seq(from=m@p[i]+1, 
                to=m@p[i+1], length.out=max(0, m@p[i+1] - m@p[i]))
    r[m@j[inds]+1] <- m@x[inds]     ## set values
    return(r)
}
```

Check equality of results across methods (all `TRUE`):

```
all.equal(S2C[1,],S1[1,])
all.equal(S2C[1,],S2R[1,])
all.equal(my_row_extract(S2R,1),S2R[1,])
all.equal(my_row_extract(S2R,17),S2R[17,])
```

Benchmark:

```
benchmark(S1[1,], S2C[1,], S2R[1,], my_row_extract(S2R,1),
          columns=c("test","elapsed","relative"))
##                     test elapsed relative
## 4 my_row_extract(S2R, 1)   0.015    1.154
## 1                S1[1, ]   0.013    1.000
## 2               S2C[1, ]   0.563   43.308
## 3               S2R[1, ]   4.113  316.385
```

The special-purpose extractor is competitive with base matrices. `S2R` is super-slow, even for row extraction (surprisingly); however, `?"dgRMatrix-class"` does say

> *Note:* The column-oriented sparse classes, e.g., ‘dgCMatrix’, are preferred and better supported in the ‘Matrix’ package.

Comment: The function works correctly only if the row _i_ is not empty.  If you want to handle empty rows use something like `inds <- seq(from=m@p[i]+1, to=m@p[i+1], length.out=max(0, @p[i+1] - m@p[i]))` for the third row.